# Android ActionBar XML attributes issue

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I followed the instruction in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
to make action bars. Basically, it works for one activity but not the other..
after change XML attribute to 'android' instead of what the developer sugguested 'yourapp' from xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", it works for the one that failed initially

What is the problem here?

Following are the codes for each menu
This works for OutputPaymentActivity but NOT OutputRefinanceActivity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:slc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.simpleloancalculator.OutputPaymentActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        slc:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
        android:title="@string/email"/>

</menu>
```

vice versa:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.simpleloancalculator.OutputRefinanceActivity" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
        android:title="@string/email"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace with this :**

```
xmlns:slc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.simpleloancalculator"
```

this value (com.example.simpleloancalculator) replace with your package name.